# Selenium wait for element to reload

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a page that has a list of comments (each comment is a div and the list is a div containing all of these).
There's a button at the end of the page to load more comments. These comments are load as an "infinite scroll". They are appended to the ones present.

I have to perform in Selenium a click to this button to bring more comments and then **wait until the new comments are loaded**.

How do I do this? I have no way of differentiating the new comments from the old ones. Is there a hook to know when an element changes? I mean, when an element gets added more elements to it's children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a *hook*; Selenium seems to implement these waits with "polling" rather than hooks.

So, can you wait on a condition, the condition being that the list contains the expected new number of comments?

Comment: Hmm that might work. Could you further exemplify how I would do that?

Comment: Never mind, I found out how. If anyone got the idea but does not know to put it into code
you can check this answer https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8701